# How to exclude files/dirs from CPack binary using CMake

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a project structured like below:

```
\build
\deps
\src
CMakeLists.txt
clean.cmake
```

There are some library dependencies located in `deps`. All these libraries have CMake `install` command.

After `install`, the output files will be put in `build` directory:

```
\build\fin\bin
\build\fin\lib
\build\fin\include
```

In my case, I will run `cmake package` to generate a binary install package, it generates something similar in `_CPack_Packages`.

The problem is I don't need `lib` and `include` to be included in the binary. But I haven't found a solution yet.

I tried the following methods:

1. `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` and `CPACK_SOURCE_STRIP_FILES`.

These are for packaging the source I think, not working for my case.

2. Use post install script `instal(SCRIPT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/clean.cmake")` to remove the unnecessary files/dirs.

In `clean.cmake`, `if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/ProjectA.lib")` returned `FALSE`, there is nothing in the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` directory when the script was running, but I can find the files after it finished.

3. Try to modify `install_manifest.txt`. I haven't found a way to access this file correctly. I'm not sure this would work.

Thank you for your help!

---

Edit:

The `install` command like below:

```
install(TARGETS ${INS_TARGETS}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT applications
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libraries
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT libraries
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use component install.

1. Add component label for each `install` command:

   ```
   install(TARGET app DESTINATION ... COMPONENT applications)
   install(TARGET library DESTINATION ... COMPONENT libraries)
   install(FILES <headers> DESTINATION ... COMPONENT headers)
   ```
2. Turn on component install in CPack and list components you want to install:

   ```
   set(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
   set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL applications)
   include(CPack)
   ```

More information : http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Component_Install_With_CPack

Comment: I tried to avoid modify the CMake scripts because there are third-party libs. But so far it seems this would be a working solution. Thank you!

Comment: You can specify separate components for `RUNTIME` and for `ARCHIVE`: `install(TARGETS ... RUNTIME DESTINATION lib COMPONENT runtime ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT development)`.

Comment: The usage of `set(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)` creates a tar for each component. How do you tell it to put all required components into a single package?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan it creates the components that you set in CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL.